# How to scrape Magento product quantity?

Tags: php, magento, web-scraping, web-crawler, phpquery

I am scraping a Magento website.

I need to get quantity of product as well.

Here is website [www.nyxsleek.com](http://www.nyxsleek.com)

I am scraping quantity by inputting quantity one by one until it gives error in cart.

I want to know is there any way I can determine quantity in stock of a product?

Answers from Magento experts will be appreciated

Comment: Where do you want to get this quantity? On a certain template file?

Comment: I dont have access to code of website :( I am just scraping this site